# Kinect sdk 1.8 installation failed after uninstalling Kinect sdk 2.0

Tags: kinect-sdk

Installation of Kinect sdk 1.8 failed after installing and uninstalling Kinect sdk 2.0. Searched for solution only to find several had encountered the same problem, is there a solution except to reinstall the system?

Comment: I have a PC with Windows 8.1, and I have both SDKs (1.8 and 2.0) installed and perfectly working (1.8 with Kinect for Xbox 360, and 2.0 with Kinect for Xbox One)... So your situation sounds strange to me...

Comment: @VitoGentile I've reinstalled 2.0 sdk and it didn't work still,  so i thought the problem here maybe that uninstalling the 2.0 sdk left something to system.